# Having an issue with record.copy in suitescript 2.0

Tags: suitescript2.0

When an RMA is created, I am trying to make a copy of the Sales Order the RMA was created from. When I save, nothing happens. No record is created, no error is thrown. Curious what is missing.

```
function afterSubmit(context) {
    var rec = context.newRecord;
    var type = context.type;
    var createdFrom = rec.getValue('createdfrom');
    var rmaReason = rec.getValue('custbody_rma_reason');
            
    if (type === context.UserEventType.CREATE) {
                      
        var objRecord = nsRecord.copy({
            type: nsRecord.Type.SALES_ORDER,
            id: createdFrom,
            isDynamic: true
        });
        log.debug('so', createdFrom);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `record.save()` method to save the copied record instance.

```
var objRecord = nsRecord.copy({
  type: nsRecord.Type.SALES_ORDER,
  id: createdFrom,
  isDynamic: true
});

var copiedRecord = objRecord.save();
```